# Merging two dataframes with different structure using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge data from one dataframe onto another.
The main dataframe consists of survey answers with a year, month, and region variable.
The data I need to merge onto this is the weather data for that specific month. This data is stored in my second data frame for weather stations with a year variable, a temperature average variable for each month (eg. value1, value2, ... value12), and a region variable.

I've tried to merge the two dataframes on region and year, and my plan was then afterwards to select the average temperature variable which coincides with the survey.

```
df1
---------------------------
year  month     regions
2002  january   Pais Vasco
2002  february  Pais Vasco 
2003  march     Pais Vasco 
2002  november  Florida
2003  december  Florida
...   ...      ...
---------------------------

df2
-----------------------------------------------
year  value1  value2  ...  value12  regions
2002  10      11      ...  9        Pais Vasco
2003  11      11      ...  10       Pais Vasco
2004  12      11      ...  10       Pais Vasco
2002  11      11      ...  9        Florida
2003  10      11      ...  9        Florida
-----------------------------------------------
```

So in this example I need for my first survey observation to get the corresponding temperature (value1) data from the region Pais Vasco and year 2002.

When I tried to merge with

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = "left", on =["regions", "year"])
```

I just get a dataframe with way more observations than my original survey dataframe.

Comment: Is `'month' in df2.columns`? Or is it stored as value1, value2, etc. in wide format?

Comment: You merge on `regions` but the column is called `region`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Do the two tables match up 1:1? There should only be one weather observation per region/year combination.

Comment: ifly6: the month info in df2 is stored in wide format as value1, value2, etc. so Maybe splitting that info into two columns would help?

Jordan: the two data frames does not match up, there is only one weather observation per region/year combination.

Comment: Look at my answer, you'll see that I split the `valueX` columns into a month column taking whatever value `X` is given.

Comment: @ifly6 thanks! I'll give it a shot tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert this data to [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) format. Assuming `value1`, `value2` etc. correspond to `value` and `month`, then use `pd.wide_to_long` to turn it into long tidy format then merge.

```
tidy = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['value'], i=['year', 'region'], j='month', sep='') \
    .reset_index()
```

You need to normalise your months so that they are all either numbers or integers. How you do this is outside the scope of this answer.

Then,

```
df1.merge(tidy, on=['year', 'month', 'region'], how='left', validate='1:1')
```

If this raises an error, then you have multiple observations for the same `['year', 'month', 'region']` key. Fix that by dropping duplicates. How you do so is almost certainly based heavily on your data.

---

sobek noticed that you have a typo, saying `'regions'` rather than `'region'` in your merge command. Make sure you're referring to columns that actually exist.

Comment: Can't you merge on string columns as well? It will mess with the ordering, but apart from that?

Comment: You mean the form of storing months? It doesn't matter what form they are.

Comment: I guess i don't understand why you say that one needs to normalize the months.

Comment: In `df1` they are named like January, February, March... The output from `tidy` will have those months as `[1, 2, 3...]`. Those won't match without converting one of them to the other's format.

Comment: So I just tried your code, and it got me half way there, however the variables I input as the index (i = [...]) and the suffix (j = "month") all end up as the new index and not as separate variables. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it with
`weather = weather.reset_index(level=['ID', 'YEAR', 'regions', 'month'])`